# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chi1'

Tags: python, pytorch

I am new in python. I am trying to import arguments into my class "**inverse_model**" . I call a function "**get_model**s" to do that. But it gives me the error "****init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'zz'**:

I appreciate help. Please see code below:

```
    def get_models(args):
    
    
    zz=torch.tensor(args.chi_Initialize)
    inverse_net = inverse_model(in_channels=len(args.chi),zz=zz,resolution_ratio=args.resolution_ratio,nonlinearity=args.nonlinearity)
    
    return inverse_net


class inverse_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels,zz,resolution_ratio=6,nonlinearity="tanh"):
        super(inverse_model, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.zz=zz
        self.resolution_ratio = resolution_ratio #vertical scale mismtach between seismic and EI
        self.activation =  nn.ReLU() if nonlinearity=="relu" else nn.Tanh()
```

Comment: Please post your code as text and not a screenshot

Comment: Your class doesn't work , you can't have argument with default value BEFORE argument with no default value

Comment: @azro thanks. but all my arguments have default value.

Comment: @salabb not in the posted code they don't

Comment: Apart from the parameters in `__init__` that come after `nonlinearity` not having default values (which is a syntax error), your code also won't run since it's not possible to use a class before defining it.

Comment: arg.chi_Initialize=0, rest of the arguments also look default. could you please identify which argument is not default here?

Comment: @salabb None of the `chi` arguments in `__init__` have default values.

Comment: Side note: have a look at *args and **kwargs. Having all those parameters is a bit awkward.

Comment: well those arguments are imported into the inverse_model class .@BTables, if  chi1=args.chi_Initialize, aint those taken as defaults. @Johnny Mopp, i tred args, kwargs. thanks

Comment: @John Byro. i tried your suggested script. Did not work out. thanks

Comment: @salabb the default values are located in the `__init__` function. Doing `chi1=args.chi_Initialize` simply passes in `args.chi_Initialize` as a value for a named argument.

Comment: thanks guys.  I learned an important concept of default and non-default arguments. However, I tried what is said. but still no solution :)

Comment: Can you upload your modified code in question , We might look into it again. It should work now. Update your question to have a look

Comment: @John Byro. Thanks for keeping a check. I re submit the code. only the argument is "zz". it is not working. same error.

Comment: Code is working good for me , `exit 0` status, can you update the input for get_model method, i could verify fully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After default argument, python does not allow to have non default argument.

Modify your constructor to

```
def __init__(self, in_channels,
                 chi1,chi2,chi3,chi4,chi5,chi6,chi7,chi8,chi9,
                 chi10,chi11,chi12, resolution_ratio=6,nonlinearity="tanh"):
```

**Updated answer : Revision 1 (updated question)**

```
import torch
from torch import nn


class inverse_model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, zz, resolution_ratio=6, nonlinearity="tanh"):
        super(inverse_model, self).__init__()
        self.in_channels = in_channels
        self.zz = zz
        self.resolution_ratio = resolution_ratio  # vertical scale mismtach between seismic and EI
        self.activation = nn.ReLU() if nonlinearity == "relu" else nn.Tanh()

def get_models(args):
    zz = torch.tensor(args.chi_Initialize)
    inverse_net = inverse_model(in_channels=len(args.chi), zz=zz, resolution_ratio=args.resolution_ratio,
                                nonlinearity=args.nonlinearity)

    return inverse_net
```

It returns `exit 0` as status.

Comment: @sal abb , can you provide sample input?

Comment: Thank you again. I do not know what was wrong. I closed and restart and it  worked. I used your instructions . Many thanks.